# strings not getting added to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to add string objects to an array inside for loop. Below is my code;

```
for (int i=0;i<[retrievedArray count];i++)
{
    NSString *temp = [[retrievedArray objectAtIndex:i] OfficialName];
    [detailPgArray addObject:temp];
}
```

I have 10 objects inside retrievedArray (not as direct strings, but as OfficialName)

But for some reason, at the end of the for loop, detailPgArray has 0 objects. Please help.

Comment: You can format code by highlighting it and then pressing the "{}" button.

Comment: Is detailPgArray nil? The code looks fine but if detailPgArray is nil it will always return a count of 0

Comment: I just declare detailPgArray in the .h file and am trying to set it inside this for loop. I have not set it to nilanywhere else.

Comment: `OfficialName` should be `officialName` if you want to follow Objective-C naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

detailPgArray is more than likely nil. You need to allocate somewhere. If it is an instance variable try the following.

```
[detailPgArray release];
detailPgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[retrievedArray count]];

for (int i=0;i<[retrievedArray count];i++)
{
    NSString *temp = [[retrievedArray objectAtIndex:i] OfficialName];
    [detailPgArray addObject:temp];
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for this wonderful basic learning...YOU ALL ROCK..UNFORTUNATELY I COULD NOT ACCEPT ALL YOUR ANSWERS !

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you neglected to allocate and initialize detailPgArray. If it's nil, then your -addObject: calls will go merrily into the void and any later calls to -count will return nil or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `detailPgArray` is nil. You need to create an array to go in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you can send a message to `nil` and the application won't crash -- and that is what's happening in your code with that `addObject` call. You have to alloc and init the array.